# PingFederate TimeZone change option

Tags: pingfederate

How to change/alter the timezone in PingFederate 6.10 version. So that it can be reflected in all SAML and OPENToken and in the receiver end, user will receive the token with newly updated date information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend! From the [Ping support forums](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Administration/How-to-change-the-timezone-in-the-request-log-in-PingFederate-6-10-and-newer):

You can adjust this by editing the file: `/pingfederate/etc/jetty-runtime.xml`.

In this you will find a line `<Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>`

Adjust the Greenwich Mean Time(GMT) offset by adding or subtracting the number of hours you are from GMT.

For Example, for Eastern Standard Time(EST) with Daylight Savings Time(DST) offset it would be: `<Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT-4</Set>`